# How can I get the updated data without refresh the page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a component with create a blog. It works fine and navigates me to the home after adding the new blog object in the database, but I have to refresh the page to be able to see the updated data. So how can I see the updated blogs after navigation without refreshing the page?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const Create = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [body, setbody] = useState("");
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("mario");
  const [isPending, setPending] = useState(false);
  const nav = useNavigate();

  const newBlog = { title, body, author };

  const handelSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(title);
    console.log(body);
    console.log(author);

    setPending(true);

    fetch("http://localhost:3001/blogs", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(newBlog),
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("newBlog Added");

      setPending(false);

      nav("/");
    });
    console.log(newBlog);
  };

  return (
    <div className="create">
      <h2>Add a New Blog</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handelSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="">Blog title:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          required
          value={title}
          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="">Blog Body:</label>
        <textarea
          required
          value={body}
          onChange={(e) => setbody(e.target.value)}
        ></textarea>

        <label htmlFor="">Blog author:</label>
        <select value={author} onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="mario">Mario</option>
          <option value="magdy">Magdy</option>
        </select>
        {!isPending && <button>Add Blog</button>}
        {isPending && <button disabled>Adding Blog</button>}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

//Home component implementation
import React from "react";
import Blog from "./../blog/Blog";

export const Home = () => {
  // const { data, flag, error } = useFetch("http://localhost:3001/blogs");
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState(null);
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/blogs")
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw Error("Error in the API");
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setBlogs(data);
        setFlag(!flag);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e.message);
        setError(e.message);
        setFlag(!flag);
      });
    return () => {};
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="home">
      {blogs && <Blog blogs={blogs} title="All Blogs" />}
      {flag && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {error !== null && <p>{error}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
 

//Blog component implementation

import React from "react";
import { Link, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { BlogDetails } from "../BlogDetails/BlogDetails";
import { Create } from "../create/Create";

import { Error } from "../Notfound/Error";

function Blog({ blogs, title }) {

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={
          <div>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            {blogs.map((blog) => {
              return (
                <div className="blog" key={blog.id}>
                  <Link to={`blogs/${blog.id}`}>
                    <h3>{blog.title}</h3>
                    <p>{blog.body}</p>
                    <h6>Written By {blog.author}</h6>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        }
      ></Route>
      <Route path="/create" element={<Create />}></Route>
      <Route path="/blogs/:id" element={<BlogDetails />}></Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<Error />}></Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default Blog;
```

Comment: A simple idea would be added a useEffect hook and run the `fetch` function inside it every `x` seconds using `setInterval`

Comment: @LoXatoR I tried to make it as below, but unfortunately, when i try to click the new Blog button it add an empty object to the database and redirects me automatically to the home ,                
 ` useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/blogs", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(newBlog),
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("newBlog Added");


      setPending(false);

      nav("/");
    });
  }) `

Comment: Could you make a reproducible sandbox of your issue, it will be more helpful to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update the `blogs` state, which is declared at the main point of the application, which is, for example, `App.jsx`, you must pass the state `blogs` and the set-state-action `setBlogs` as properties to the child component. For example:

The state in `App.jsx`:

```
const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState(null)
```

The child component (on which you will update the `blogs` state):

```
<Create blogs={blogs} setBlogs={setBlogs} />
```

On the `fetch`'s `then`

```
fetch("http://localhost:3001/blogs", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify(newBlog),
}).then((data) => {
  console.log("newBlog Added");

  setPending(false);
  setBlogs([...blogs, newBlog])

  nav("/");
});
console.log(newBlog);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the perblem sloved , i really appreciate it